# Javascript print page

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

Hi I have a survey page(survey.aspx) with question and answers.
some of the answers have Radio buttons and check boxes.
This page has a print button. When the user clicks on the print button
another page(survey_print.aspx) opens up with the print content.
I have all the content Radio buttons and check boxes in the print page.
But how to show the checked Radio buttons and check boxes in the print page.
This has to be done using Javascript or jquery.
Any idea how this can be done.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use a [print stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) on your survey page, eliminating the need for a separate `survey_print.aspx`.

By using a print stylesheet, you also gain the benefit of things working correctly if your user clicks their browser's print button (or presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).  You can just change your page's print button to call `window.print()`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as both pages are pulled from the same web site, a script in one can affect the other.  Here's an example:

```
function printForm() {
    var preview = window.open(urlPrint);
    var inputs = document.forms.myForm.elements;
    var previewInputs = preview.document.forms.myForm.elements;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        var previewInput = previewInputs[i];

        if (input.checked) previewInput.checked = true;
        if (input.selected) previewInput.selected = true;
    }

    preview.print();
}
```

I've put [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gbALC/3/) up on jsFiddle (though it creates the preview window with [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write) rather than a separate URL).

`document.forms`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms

`form.elements`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements

Comment: Hi Ben, your solution not working. Its opening the print page but the radio buttons are not checked in the print page.I added your code to the survey.aspx page and called the printform() function from print button onclick event. Am I doing correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ben, In firefox if I debug using firebug, its working . But withou debug its not showing the values. Any idea what could be the problem.

Comment: Hi Ben, can I get little help here. When I put alert in if condition then the values are passed to the print window, otherwise values are not passed to print window. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @Henry — Sorry!  I wasn't able to get back on SO until now.  I've updated the code so that it works with radio buttons as well and put [a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/gbALC/3/) up on jsFiddle.

Comment: HI Ben, thanks for the solution, Unfortunately , its not working. I guess when the window.open(url) gets executed , the cursor is not moving further.So the values are not getting passed. I appreciate for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to send the selected values to your print page (as POST or GET parameters). If you are using jQuery you might want to look into the [click](http://jqapi.com/#p=click) function and the [:input](http://jqapi.com/#p=input-selector) selector.

Another idea would be to omit the print page completely and provide some CSS for the [print media type](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml). This style is then only used for the print view (you could hide the websites navigation, header, footer etc.).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Comment: Hi Wolfram, How to pass these values from survey page to survey_print page. Is it possible can you show me some code.